# Blocking commands from all channels Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i'm looking for blocking user's commands from every channel in the discord server. I want the commands to be executable only by private chat. I'm using last version of Discord.js but i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Hi, please show us what you've tried so far. Some code and where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.guild) {return false}; // The message was sent in a guild. return false will prevent the code below from running.

    
    // The message was sent in DMs. You can execute your commands here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check `if (message.channel.type != 'dm') return;` to completely ignore all messages that are sent in a server.